# lsi megaraid convert raid 0 to raid 10 without data loss?

Tags: raid10, lsi, megaraid, raid0

I am using a lsi megaraid controller with firmware version 2.130.353-1819 (aug 09 2012). 
There I had a raid 5 with 4x4tb disks.
What I wanted to do is to migrate from raid 5 to raid 10. The megaraid storage manager gave me only the opportunity to migrate to raid 0 live without dataloss. I did that. took me about 30h. 
Is it now possible to convert this VD to raid 10?
From what I read, I must configure two raid 1 VD and add a tripe to make it raid 10. but I now have one raid 0 with 4 hdds.

Removing disks in raid 0 means dataloss, so what can I do? 
I dont't have enough space anywhere to backup the 7TB of data (drive group ith 16tb -> 14.5 net space, 8tb free).

[megaraid storage manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8370.png)

Comment: `now have one raid 0 with 4 hdds.` I suspect you are out of luck at this point.  You are probably going to need to buy a large HD and make a backup, and do it fast because if any of your drives fail you lose everything.

Answer (score 1):

According to the good old "MegaRAID SAS Software User's Guide", migrations are allowed for the following RAID levels:

- RAID 0 to RAID 1
- RAID 0 to RAID 5
- RAID 1 to RAID 5
- RAID 1 to RAID 6
- RAID 5 to RAID 6

It seems that your only option is to find a spare space somewhere, migrate your data, and reconfigure the array from scratch.